# Create an object to access a SubClassed NSview in cocoa program

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, subclass, nsview

i'm having a subclassed NSView. i created an object as below:

```
CustomView * ClockT = [[CustomView alloc]init];  
ClockT.tZone = @"Canada/Yukon";  
[HolderView addSubview:ClockT];
```

but the view does not shown. how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]` passing a meaningful frame or assign a frame after creation.

Basically there are only three reasons why a view may be invisible:

1. Wrong frame: zero frame size or origin is out of the visible coordinates;
2. Does not have a visible superview, i.e. not added as a subview;
3. isHidden property set to YES.

Comment: got it! i used as` CustomView * ClockT = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:[HolderView frame]];`.

Comment: how to make superView to be visible?

Comment: If the superview is the content view of the window on the screen, it is visible. Otherwise, check the thee conditions above.

Comment: now the subView was created. but the view not properly displayed [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17691614/2515572)