# NSView subView not visible after added to superView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, subview

this is my final window [image]

i added 4 subviews (last 4 in 2nd image) to the base view. but not displaying the view. after manual resizing window the subviews appeared as below.
[image]

how can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
baseView.needsDisplay = YES;
```

-- or --

```
subview.superview.needsDisplay = YES;
```

Comment: Please elaborate how calling `needsDisplay` solves the OP's issue.

Comment: He's added 4 subviews but hasn't refreshed their superview… The clue was that manually resizing made them appear.

Comment: Thanks @geowar, you are right. The problem is with view drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSScrollView:

```
    NSScrollView* scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] init];
    [scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller: YES];
    [scrollView setHasVerticalScroller: YES];
    self.contentView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1.0e7, 1.0e7)];
    [self.contentView addSubview: [NSImageView ...]];        
    [self.contentView addSubview: [NSImageView ...]];        
    ...
    [scrollView setDocumentView: self.contentView];
    self.view = scrollView;
```

Or use Minimum Size for Window.

Comment: y the subviews are invisible in window?

Comment: you can add all subviews. they should not be hide

Comment: i inserted scroll view in Interface builder below the baseview. but the problem still exists.